# How would I echo a specific table on a database?

Tags: php, database

So I am trying to echo a user's amount of money they have made, but it is not working. I am using this code but it is showing all of the users payout. How would I show the user his payout and not others?

```
<?php $user_details = $db->select("SELECT * FROM 'as_user_details'");
foreach ( $user_details as $row ) {
    echo $row['payout']; 
} ?>
```

Comment: Use the filter of mysql `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Only fetch the data of that particular user from the dB rather fetching data for all the users.

```
<?php 
    $user_details = $db->select("SELECT * FROM 'as_user_details' where id = '$user_id' ");
    echo $user_details['payout']; 
?>
```

Comment: like this? <?php $user_details = $db->select("SELECT * FROM 'as_user_details' where id = '$used_id' ");
foreach ( $user_details as $row ) {
    echo $row['payout']; 
} ?>

Comment: if you only getting one row returned there is no need to loop

Comment: how do i get rid of the loop and fix it?

Comment: After using filter `where` you only have a single row for that user, so you can show his details directly without using loop.

Comment: @nogad look at my comment above

Comment: @AnkitJain how would that look like

Comment: User_id is the filter which filter out the data from the db according to the current user id

Comment: Whats the error it is showing and show the db structure

Comment: @AnkitJain well they have two tables, users and user details, and its saying "Undefined variable: row" on the error log

Comment: Do you have `id` column in your db and do you have any user id from which you can filter put his data

Comment: they bth have user id